# Disable Newsletter complete

Tags: magento2.2, newsletter

I would like to disable the newsletter-module of Magento 2.2.5.

Tried via console:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Newsletter
```

But there are to many dependencies:

```
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_Newsletter because modules depend on it:
Magento_Store: Magento_Store->Magento_Catalog->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Directory: Magento_Directory->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Eav: Magento_Eav->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Theme: Magento_Theme->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Customer: Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Backend: Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_AdminNotification: Magento_AdminNotification->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Indexer: Magento_Indexer->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Cms: Magento_Cms->Magento_Theme->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Catalog: Magento_Catalog->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Payment: Magento_Payment->Magento_Quote->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport: Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter
Magento_Config: Magento_Config->Magento_Backend->Magento_Customer->Magento_Newsletter ...
```

Is that normal?

Answer (score 3):

I would advice to just remove the newsletter block to not break the other dependencies like this:

You can remove this block completely via layout with **remove="true"**:

> app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/Spiceli/Magento_Newsletter/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```